# How to run a previous command in an Emacs shell?

Tags: eshell

Of course when I am in Terminal and I press the up arrow key, it goes to the previous command. However, when I hit the <kbd>M-x</kbd> keys and type `shell` an integrated shell comes up in Emacs:

[image: Shell in Emacs]

However, if I type a command and press up, this happens:

[image: When I press the up button in Shell Emacs]

How do I get back to the last command I typed?

Comment: You can also go up with navigation keys to the line with the command you want to execute and hit `RET`.  Of course `C-up` is much easier.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function that *cycles backwards through input history, saving input.* is `comint-previous-input`

It is bound to <kbd>C-up</kbd>, <kbd>M-p</kbd>.

Comment: But of course control-up is already bound to something in MacOS...

Comment: On a Mac, I added this to my init.el file: (global-set-key (kbd "H-p") 'comint-previous-input) -- this works well when I'm in the shell and want to get back to the previous command. The H is for fn functional key.

Answer (score 7):

Just found an answer on Super User:

[How do you run the previous command in emacs shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/139815/how-do-you-run-the-previous-command-in-emacs-shell)

<kbd>M-p</kbd> goes to the previous command.

Comment: This is much easier and user friendly

Answer (score 5):

You could use [helm-eshell-history](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-27) for interactive history selection, and replace the original `C-c C-l`:

```
(require 'helm-eshell)

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "M-l")  'helm-eshell-history)))

;; for shell-mode
(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-comint-input-ring)
```

[image: helm-eshell-history]

Answer (score 3):

My favorite commands for cycling through shell command history are `comint-previous-matching-input-from-input` and `comint-next-matching-input-from-input`. If the prompt is empty, they will behave exactly like `comint-previous-input` and `comint-next-input` cycling through all history items. Though if you have entered `rake`, for example, they will cycle through your shell command history of commands starting with `rake`.

By default these are bound to `C-c M-r` and `C-c M-s` respectively, but I find those not ideal. I'm personally binding them to `M-TAB` and `<M-S-tab>`.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed in Eshell a little.
The module `em-hist.el` is implemented based on the minor mode `eshell-hist-mode` since commit [1ee0192b79 in the Emacs git-repro](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/1ee0192b792124663a0a40a729dd83c047d21535).
Currently, this commit is only in the `master` branch of Emacs (i.e., `28.0` as of today). It has been reverted in the Emacs `27.1` by the commit [478638e470](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/478638e4706716b74de5b1aa3e85c8fd943f17ba) because of [Bug#41370](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2020-05/msg01265.html).

So here is my updated working solution for using helm-eshell-history

```
   (use-package eshell
     :config
     (require 'em-hist)      
     (use-package eshell-git-prompt
       :config
       ;; the powerline prompt is best but I've no idea how to shorten it to the last directory.
       (eshell-git-prompt-use-theme 'powerline)
       (define-advice eshell-git-prompt-powerline-dir (:override () short)
         "Show only last directory."
         (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name default-directory))))
     :bind (:map eshell-hist-mode-map
                 ;; ("<down>" . 'next-line)
                 ;; ("<up>" . 'previous-line)
                 ;; ([remap eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input] . helm-eshell-history)
                 ([remap eshell-list-history] . helm-eshell-history)
                 ))
```

Comment: Dear RichieHH, I added a reference to the change in the Emacs repro. Hope that is okay for you. Just revert if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, if you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles): Use `C-c TAB` (command `icicle-comint-command`) to choose a previously entered command with completion (or cycling).

Comment: Icicles doesnt come close to the consistency and support level of helm.